# Comma necessary

Tags: commas

I have the following sentence and I need your help:

"For this case study(,) two residential areas are modelled in simulations."

Do I need the comma or not? I'd appreciate every comment.

Comment: Thanks Edwin for your answer. What I understood from the question is that I can use the comma.

Comment: Yes. Read it out and see which reading you prefer – with or without the comma. The comma codes for a slight pause. You can create different emphases. Where commas are optional, I often find the overall context or even the mood I'm in sway my choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and help Edwin